# Adding Entry to Table - Adding onto Existing Entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to add data to an existing table, where it can identify a value (like name or ID#) and add in a new piece of data into that row for the individual.

See Pic 1: The person using this guide will click "yes" or "no" if they want to move the person forward.  I want to record that yes/no in their database.  (Note: each new candidate gets their HR Guide with their name on it.  If you are listed on the Short list (see pic 2), you will get a HR Guide created for you.  So the name of the tab is unpredictable, which is why things like vlookups or other formulas will not work.)

[image: Pic of Tab 1: HR Guide]

Here is the image of where I want the input to go.  Based on the name matching in column C, I want it to input the Yes/No in Column I

[image: Pic of Tab 2: Table of Info]

I have no VBA code to share as I have no clue where to start.  I have looked around trying to find a solution or something to work off of, but cannot find something that is close enough for me to figure it out (usually that works for me, but not this time...).  So any help/direction you can provide would be VERY helpful!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally one would use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` for a task like this.

Comment: So, is the first screenshot like a data entry form that will be overwritten with the next candidate? In that case, you may want to use a proper data entry form, not the worksheet grid. These are called UserForms in VBA. Or create a VBA routine that copies the data from the Entry sheet into the other sheets at the push of a button, then clears the sheet.  I still don't understand how there already is a "mouse guide" sheet, though, if the guide will be created only for people on the short list. You may want to step back and work on the information architecture a bit more.